# How do I take a screenshot with dimensions?

Tags: screenshot

I need to capture hundreds of screenshots, each the same size. Is there an application that would allow me to capture a portion of my screen with fixed dimensions? For example, I would like the fixed region to appear as soon as I press the screenshot button then capture it when I left click.

I am currently using the default screenshot app that comes with Ubuntu 12.10 and the feature to capture an area works for me but not knowing what the dimensions are is an issue.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[**Shutter**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shutter) [image: Install Shutter]

Shutter is a feature-rich screenshot program. You can take a screenshot of a specific area, window, your whole screen, or even of a website - apply different effects to it, draw on it to highlight points, and then upload to an image hosting site, all within one window.

You can set the size of default selection in it's Preferences. Go to *Edit > Preferences > Advanced* and change the value of *start with selection size of*.

[image: Shutter Preferences]

You can get more details about Shutter on it's [website](http://shutter-project.org/).

Comment: No more copying and pasting screenshots to edit dimensions! Thank you very much.

Comment: 10 years late, but maybe still helpful to others: If you wish to use the selection size feature just by pressing your "Print Screen" key, you need to bind the PrintScreen key to the "shutter -s" command! This way I managed to take several screenshots in rapid order without having to go back to the shutter GUI again and again.