# How do I take a screenshot?

Tags: screenshot

I'm not really sure since I'm still new to Linux distros in general

Comment: Maybe this could help you: [How do I take a screenshot with dimensions?](http://askubuntu.com/q/262253/62483) & [How to take a screenshot of a whole desktop with app menu selection?](http://askubuntu.com/q/15639/62483) & [How do I take screenshots with a delay?](http://askubuntu.com/q/252281/62483) & [How can I take a screenshot of the login screen?](http://askubuntu.com/q/43458/62483) & [How to take a screenshot every n second?](http://askubuntu.com/q/50958/62483) & [Can I take a screenshot of a virtual console?](http://askubuntu.com/q/12208/62483) Full list: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6121610/

Comment: Agreed - this may well be a duplicate of something, but it's not a duplicate of *that* question.

Comment: See also: [How to take screenshot of indicator menus?](http://askubuntu.com/q/126787/62483)

Answer (score 100):

Just press the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key.

[image]

You may find the Pictures in your Home Picture folder, this will normally work with any operative system.

Comment: I tried that but nothing happened. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to go to `~/Pictures/` using the `Files` program and look for a file named `Screenshot from 2020-02-14 12-09-09.png`

Comment: What about for Mac's? All of these suggestions assume a `Print` or `Prnt Scrn` key.

Comment: @fukanchik in Lubuntu, the image is saved in `/home/yourusername` as something like `2020-03-29-122645_1366x768_scrot.png`

Comment: What if you do not have a `Print Screen` button? Many keyboards these days omit those

Comment: The button may also be called "stamp".

Comment: that will only do the whole screen

Comment: @PhilipRego there's anything in the question that asks for a region or window?

Comment: @Braiam no. Does the question ask for the whole window?

Comment: @PhilipRego no, it asks for a screenshot, and my answer provides exactly that. A whole-"screen" shot.

Answer (score 81):

<kbd>Shift + Prnt Scrn</kbd> allows you to print a selection of the screen.

<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> alone will take a screenshot.

Only GNOME 2.x: Hold <kbd>Super</kbd> (The Windows Icon on your keyboard) to display all key shortcuts. [Here](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en) on GNOME Shell.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about the windows key!

Comment: holding the windows key doesn't work for me (Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: I think holding SUPER/WIN to display shortcuts is actually Unity desktop feature, not MATE/Gnome 2 or Gnome 3.

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 39):

View the available short-cuts under

On GNOME Shell (17.10+): Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Screenshots

[image: screenshot]

or on Unity (before 17.10): Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard

[image]

If you have less options view [Create custom short-cuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170163/how-do-i-set-a-shortcut-to-screenshot-a-selected-area)

If you would like to use a tool you may want to use Gimp, Shutter, etc. View more in [This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6558/what-screenshot-tools-are-available)

Comment: As of Ubunutu 14.04 "screenshot of window" only takes the part in the current workspace.  For example if your window spans more than one visible workspace, because it is longer or wider, then only the picture is cropped to the current workspace.

Comment: thanks also worked for me, new ubuntu upgrade just changed a bit the layout:  https://imgur.com/a/KWt19

Comment: Great tip! FYI, on Ubuntu 18.04 (and maybe earlier, too) this is Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard

Answer (score 19):

Open Dash (upper icon on the launcher) and search screenshot.

Comment: Thanks. I'm running Linux in a VM under OSX and my keyboard does not have a Prt Scr key..

Answer (score 18):

**Update**: Shutter [got removed from Debian/*Ubuntu](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/shutter) repos because [it uses deprecated Perl modules](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=870418).

---

You can use "shutter" for taking a snapshot of a selected area. You need to do

```
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

Comment: I've moved to this due to `gnome-screenshot` adding an orange tint to the background of selections on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: For a selected area in Ubuntu: ctrl+shift+print. No need to install extra stuff anymore

Comment: It will be back in Debian Bookworm and Ubuntu Jammy.

Answer (score 9):

**Taking it and saving it to *~/Pictures***

- <kbd>Print</kbd> - Take a screenshot
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Print</kbd> - Take a screenshot of a window
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Print</kbd> - Take a screenshot of an area

**Taking it and copying it to clipboard**

<sub>(just add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to the shortkeys above)</sub>

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Print</kbd> - Take a screenshot
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Print</kbd> - Take a screenshot of a window
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Print</kbd> - Take a screenshot of an area

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm going to swap those shortcuts right now. I don't want it saving the screenshots in files unless I tell it to do so

Answer (score 7):

Use GIMP. Launch GIMP and go to “File”->”Create”->”Screenshot”. Choose to capture a single window (with/without window border), the entire screen (with/without mouse pointer) or a specific region of the screen. Click on the “Snap” button to start capturing.

Comment: This is rather heavyweight for the task..

Answer (score 5):

You can refer [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html) from Ubuntu documentation on taking screenshots:

**Take a screenshot**

1. Open Screenshot from the [Activities](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-introduction.html.en#activities) overview.
2. In the Screenshot window, select whether to grab the whole screen, the current window, or an area of the screen. Set a delay if you need to select a window or otherwise set up your desktop for the screenshot. Then choose any effects you want.
3. Click Take Screenshot.
4. If you selected Select area to grab, the pointer changes into a crosshair. Click and drag the area you want for the screenshot.
5. In the Save Screenshot window, enter a file name and choose a folder, then click Save.
   Alternatively, import the screenshot directly into an image-editing application without saving it first. Click Copy to Clipboard then paste the image in the other application, or drag the screenshot thumbnail to the application.

**Keyboard shortcuts**

Quickly take a screenshot of the desktop, a window, or an area at any time using these global keyboard shortcuts:

- `Prt Scrn` to take a screenshot of the desktop.
- `Alt+Prt Scrn` to take a screenshot of a window.
- `Shift+Prt Scrn` to take a screenshot of an area you select.

When you use a keyboard shortcut, the image is automatically saved in your Pictures folder in your home folder with a file name that begins with Screenshot and includes the date and time it was taken.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Kazam Screencaster](https://launchpad.net/kazam) by:

```
sudo apt install kazam
```

Then run the app from the *Activities*.

[image: Kazam Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned **Flameshot** yet

- Homepage: https://flameshot.org/
- Source code: [github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot](https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot)

##### Install:

```
sudo apt install flameshot
```

##### Launching

After install create shortcut for

```
/usr/bin/flameshot gui
```

##### Usage

After launching the `/usr/bin/flameshot gui`, press the **Share**  button:

[image: share button flameshot cropped]

It also supports various types of annotations, etc:

[image: flameshot example annotate]