# Copy row and column of LibreOffice calc with heading?

Tags: libreoffice

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to copy row and column in Libre Office calc with headings, like you can in MS-Excel (copy as picture).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, there's no such feature in LibreOffice Calc. But **you can do essentially the same using a simple screenshot**. The easiest way is to capture the whole screen and to use a tool like GIMP for cropping the resulting image to the desired range. Fore more details how to create a screenshot, see the following Q/A's:

- [What screenshot tools are available?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6558/20661)
- [How do I take a screenshot?](https://askubuntu.com/q/346864/20661)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer - you can use an app like Ksnapshot.

Just select desired screen, crop it, copy it and paste it wherever you need.