# Options written in greek alphabets & not english

Tags: 14.04, language-support

Actually I'm kind stuck as programs have all the options written using `Greek alphabets` instead of English alphabets. It is hard enough to navigate through tools. I have just started using Ubuntu 14.04.

How can I change the language support to English from Greek using command-line in Ubuntu 14.04? .

Comment: Two questions: 1) Can you please run the `locale` command in a terminal, and let us know the output by editing your question. 2) Why do you want to use the command-line to fix it?

Comment: rajanish@Rajanish-Lenovo-G580:~$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

Comment: Well, that's consistently English, so it has nothing to do with the language/locales settings. As you mentioned in a comment on Rehan Ullah's answer, I think you need to explain the problem better.

Answer (score 1):

What! Rajanish! Tools language is in Greek alphabets. Is your whole system in Greek alphabets or only the tools language is in Greek. Please specify. Anyhow don't worry. Follow me. Open System Settings.[image: System Settings]
Then Click on Language Support.[image: Language Support]

Find English There and then Click on Apply System Wide(I think at the present yours will be selected as Greek.). Hope this helps if not please comment and give more details.

Comment: Guess what if you tell me how to post a screenshot, i might explain you the issue.

Comment: @RajanishkumarDubey Welcome back. To take a screen shot Simply press prtscn button on your keyboard. Then open your imageviewer and paste it there then upload it. Need more help must ask.

Comment: Or you could install shutter by command sudo apt-get install shutter type your password and it should install. When shutter installs run it and choose selection and draw a rectangle of the space of which you want to take a screenshot.

Comment: Or go to this page. All details are present. [link]http://askubuntu.com/questions/346864/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot